# why its failed to be surjective?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have  some  doubts/ confusion in *Kreyszig* functional analysis

My doubts  is given below [image]

Im not  getting  the  line  it may fail to  be  surjective

My thinking is  that as  $(e_1, e_2 , e_3 ,......) \rightarrow (0, e_1 , e_2 , e_3,.....)$

Here $(0, e_1 , e_2 , e_3,.....)$ is  infinite  sequence  so  we  can  said that  $(0, e_1 , e_2 , e_3,.....)=  (e_1, e_2 , e_3 ,......) $ because  both are infinite sequence so  it will be onto  that is  co-domain = range

Comment: If it's surjective, the sequence $(1,0,...,0,...)$ would be on its image. But it does not start with 0.

Comment: Your last equality does not hold, for if $(0,e_1,e_2,e_3,...)=(e_1,e_2,e_3,...)$ we would have $(0,e_1,e_2,e_3,...)-(e_1,e_2,e_3,...)=(0,0,...,0,...)$.

Comment: thanks u@AHandsomeAlien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove the zero in the starting : this is not like convergence of a sequence, which doesn't depend on the first finitely many terms.

Equality of sequences is pointwise. That is, a sequence $e_1,e_2,...$ equals $f_1,f_2,...$ if and only if $e_1= f_1, e_2 =  f_2, ...$.

For example, the sequence $(1,\frac 14 , \frac 19,...)$ cannot be in the image of the right shift, because it's first entry is not zero. This is the point Kreyszig is trying to make.